# UwAmp New php Versions not showing up in included "repo"

Tags: php, uwamp

So basically new php versions are broken, they no longer show up except the Uwamp php mirror, BUT that is not updated and seriously needs a refresh.

I have tried looking for a config file to show where the url's for the fetch of information but i can't find it any where, i suppose it's baked in to the uwamp.exe file which i can't edit. any ways, just wanted to reach out and tell you that and hope for a update soon.

*Note:

This website got all extensions (most of them anyways included) in their version, maybe able to add their repo as "extended". That would be a very cool and a nifty feature, it does work, i have been running it for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

Download PHP versions from the PHP website, extract to a folder with the same name as the zip, then add them your uWamp php/bin folder, then start uWamp control panel. It will detect any versions not installed.